# Deleting Columns in HBase

Tags: hadoop, nosql, hbase, bigdata

In HBase, calling DeleteColumn() method i.e., essentially a schema change to a column family or deleting column families will result in downtime of HBase Cluster?

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more what u are trying to do?

Comment: I would like to know whether changing schema(Removing columns from data as well as schema) will require bringing down the cluster.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The deleteColumn method on a [Delete mutation](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Delete.html) of HBase deletes  specific column(s) from a specific row this is not a schema change since HBase does not retain a schema-level knowledge of columns of each row (and each row can have a different number and types of columns - think about it as a thinly populated matrix). The same is true for deleteFamily on this object.

There won't be a cluster downtime for this (and HBase will not actually delete the data until the next major compaction of the region)

If you want to drop a column family from the whole table you can do that via HBaseAdmin with the not so aptly named `deleteColumn` method (or the shell with `alter 'table_name', {NAME => 'family_name', METHOD => 'delete'}`) - in this case the table needs to be disabled first so while HBase won't suffer a downtime, the specific table will