# Specifying column names in the HBASE CREATE statement

Tags: hbase

Can i specify the HBase column names upfront - in the CREATE statement?

If yes, how?

I only understood that i can specify the column families upfront and add columns later.

**UPDATE**

Please read a good explanation on this topic here [Deleting Columns in HBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763982/deleting-columns-in-hbase/18789777#18789777)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column you are referring is called "column-qualifier" [ just to make the things clear ]

No. We cannot provide column-qualifier during table creation. This is what makes HBase schema-less. The syntax for creating tables in HBase is as follows.

```
create ‘<table name>’,’<column family>’
```

Once you have created the table, you can add rows which should belong to at-least one column-family in a table and then can belong to any column-qualifier.

If the column-qualifier is not already present, it will be created.

Comment: Please provide this link in the end of your question - it gives a pretty good explanation as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763982/deleting-columns-in-hbase/18789777#18789777 Thank you :)